# How to display channels in ListView using Graph API?

Tags: winforms, microsoft-graph-api

I’m developing a small Windows form app to test Graph API functions. I have two functionalities in the application, user's log in and get channels for specified team. I created a class that contains functions for user login and for returning channels for specified team. I have a ListView on Form in which I want to show all the channels, but when I call a function for returning channels in button event, nothing happens, nothing is displayed in the ListView. Here is the code:

```
public static class GraphHelper  
{  

    public static GraphServiceClient graphClient;  
    public static string token;  

    private static string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };  
    public static string TokenForUser = null;  
    public static DateTimeOffset expiration;  

    private const string ClientId = "599ed98d-4356-4a96-ad37-04391e9c48dc";  

    private const string Tenant = "common"; // Alternatively "[Enter your tenant, as obtained from the Azure portal, e.g. kko365.onmicrosoft.com]"  
    private const string Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + Tenant;  

    // The MSAL Public client app  
    private static IPublicClientApplication PublicClientApp;  

    private static string MSGraphURL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/";  
    private static AuthenticationResult authResult;  

    public static GraphServiceClient GetGraphClient(string token)  
    {  
        if (graphClient == null)  
        {  
            // Create Microsoft Graph client.  
            try  
            {  
                graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(  
                    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",  
                    new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(  
                        async (requestMessage) =>  
                        {  
                            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);  
                            // This header has been added to identify our sample in the Microsoft Graph service.  If extracting this code for your project please remove.  
                            requestMessage.Headers.Add("SampleID", "uwp-csharp-snippets-sample");  

                        }));  
                return graphClient;  
            }  

            catch (Exception ex)  
            {  
                Debug.WriteLine("Could not create a graph client: " + ex.Message);  
            }  
        }  
        return graphClient;  
    }  

    public static async Task<string> GetTokenForUserAsync()  
    {  
        if (TokenForUser == null || expiration <= DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10))  
        {  
            PublicClientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)  
          .WithAuthority(Authority)  
          .WithRedirectUri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient")  
           .WithLogging((level, message, containsPii) =>  
           {  
               Debug.WriteLine($"MSAL: {level} {message} ");  
           }, LogLevel.Warning, enablePiiLogging: false, enableDefaultPlatformLogging: true)  
          .Build();  

            // It's good practice to not do work on the UI thread, so use ConfigureAwait(false) whenever possible.  
            IEnumerable<IAccount> accounts = await PublicClientApp.GetAccountsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);  
            IAccount firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();  

            try  
            {  
                authResult = await PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, firstAccount)  
                                                  .ExecuteAsync();  
            }  
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)  
            {  
                // A MsalUiRequiredException happened on AcquireTokenSilentAsync. This indicates you need to call AcquireTokenAsync to acquire a token  
                Debug.WriteLine($"MsalUiRequiredException: {ex.Message}");  

                authResult = await PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)  
                                                  .ExecuteAsync()  
                                                  .ConfigureAwait(false);  
            }  

            TokenForUser = authResult.AccessToken;  
        }  

        return TokenForUser;  
    }  

    public static async Task<User> GetMeAsync(string token)  
    {  
        GraphHelper.graphClient = GraphHelper.GetGraphClient(token);  
        try  
        {  
            // GET /me  
            return await GraphHelper.graphClient.Me  
                .Request()  
                .Select(u => new  
                {  
                    u.DisplayName  
                })  
                .GetAsync();  
        }  
        catch (ServiceException ex)  
        {  
            Console.WriteLine($"Error getting signed-in user: {ex.Message}");  
            return null;  
        }  
    }  
public static async Task<IEnumerable<Channel>> GetChannels(string teamId)  
    {  
        graphClient = GetGraphClient(token);  

        var channels = await graphClient.Teams[teamId].Channels  
            .Request()  
            .GetAsync();  

        return channels;  
    }  
}  

public partial class Form1 : Form  
{  
    public static GraphServiceClient graphClient;  
    public static string token;  
    public Form1()  
    {  
        InitializeComponent();  
    }  
      
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {  
        token = await GraphHelper.GetTokenForUserAsync();  
        User graphUser = await GraphHelper.GetMeAsync(token);  
        label2.Text = graphUser.DisplayName;  
    }  

private async void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {  
        var channels = GraphHelper.GetChannels("8557483b-a233-4710-82de-e1bdb03bb9a9").Result;  

        foreach (var ch in channels)  
        {  
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new string[] { ch.DisplayName, ch.Id});  
            listView1.Items.Add(item);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Does anyone how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call `GraphHelper.GetChannels` with `await` keyword on button click.

```
var channels = await GraphHelper.GetChannels("8557483b-a233-4710-82de-e1bdb03bb9a9");
```